# Python paramiko send 'CTRL-ALT-6-x' to exit console port

Tags: python, console, paramiko

I'm using paramiko to ssh into an access server and connect to a console port. Everything is working fine except when it's time to exit the console port, I must do a 'CTRL-ALT-6 follow by x'.

I tried:

```
x.send("\036\px")
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How can I exit the console port correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with help...

```
x.send("\036")
time.sleep(1)
x.send("x")
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is \036 doing for you? How were you able to send Ctrl+Alt+6 with that?